# Explanation division operator assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm learning assembly and I do not understand the division operator.
I know what happens if I divide the registers and the initial value that exists in them is initialized to 0.
But what do you do if there is already a value in the register?
For example:

```
mov dx, 0087h
mov ax, 6000h
mov bx, 100h
div bx
```

This is the answer: DX = 0000h, AX = 8760h
I would love if someone could explain it to me :)

Comment: Your explanation seems complete and correct. I’m not sure what you want explained. There is always a value in dx and ax before the division and a different value in them after the division.

Comment: The issue arises if you end up with a quotient that's too large to fit in the target register, which is not the case in this example.

Comment: `mov` replaces the old value with no dependency; that's why you use `mov` not `add` or something.  It doesn't matter what was there before.

Comment: You're dividing `dx:ax` by `bx`. 00876000h / 100h == 8760h.

Comment: Yes, dividing by 100h is equivalent to a right-shift by 8 bits.  That would be a lot more efficiently done with actual shifting (e.g. `shrd`, or shr/shr/OR), and is why you should never use `div` with a divisor that's known ahead of time to be a power of 2.

Comment: `div bx` divides the 32 bit number formed from `dx` (top 16 bits) and `ax` (low 16 bits) by `bx`. Quotient goes into `ax`, remainder into `dx`. As such you have `00876000h / 100h = 8760h` remainder zero.

Answer (score 2):

> ... and I do not understand the division operator.

It is plausible that this instruction is not as easy to understand as other instructions:

Unlike most other instructions, the assembler notation (`div bx`) contains only one register (`bx`) while actually three registers (`ax`, `dx` and `bx`) are involved.

This is a bit confusing for many x86 beginners - even if they know assembly language of other CPUs.

The `div` operation works the following way:

The values in `dx` and `ax` are interpreted as one 32-bit value (`dx` are the higher 16 bits); so if `dx` contains `12h` and `ax` contains `3456h`, the value is interpreted as `123456h`.

This 32-bit value is divided by the register mentioned in the instruction; `bx` in the case of `div bx`, the instruction divides the 32-bit value by the value in the `bx` register. Both the quotient and the reminder are calculated.

Let's say `bx` has the value `1000h`. Then the operation will calculate the following values:

```
123456h / 1000h = 123h    (quotient)
123456h mod 1000h = 456h  (reminder)
```

The instruction writes the quotient to the `ax` register and the reminder to the `dx` register.

As a programmer you can choose another register than `bx` (e.g. `div cx`); however, the operation will always use the registers `ax` and `dx`.

> ... the initial value that exists in them is initialized to 0.

`ax` and `dx` can be 0. Dividing the number `0` by another number is an allowed mathematical operation: `0 / n = 0`.

If the other register (in your case: `bx`) is `0` or if the quotient would be larger than 16 bits (e.g. if you divide `123456h` by `2`), the `div` operation will cause an exception.

This is similar to an `int` instruction: Some function in the operating system is called. Of course, it depends on the operating system what is done then. Typically, the operating system will stop the program and display some error message.

> But what do you do if there is already a value in the register?

I understand you question in two different ways:

**1) What happens if `ax` and `dx` are not empty?**

Registers cannot be "empty".

A register will always contain some value: An 8-bit register will always contain a value in the range 0...255.

So an assembly instruction will *never* write a value to an "empty" register, but an assembly instruction will *always* **overwrite** the value in an register.

**2) What do I do if `ax` or `dx` contains some value that I need later on?**

In this case the required value must be copied to another register or to the RAM and read back later.

You cannot use `div` without "destroying" the content of `ax` and `dx`.